# Component overlapping in JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I have added two components in JLayeredPane.
1. JWebBrowser
2. JPanel

I added JWebBrowser and JPanel in different layers. JWebBrowser is in 0 i.e bottom layer and JPanel is in 1st Layer.

```
m_LayeredPane.setLayer(m_WebBrowser, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
m_LayeredPane.add(m_WebBrowser);
m_LayeredPane.setLayer(m_WebCamPane, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);
m_LayeredPane.add(m_WebCamPane);
```

Now the problem is that JWebBrowser layer is overlapping JPanel layer.

I tried various things like moveToFront() method, defining position at run time, putting both component in same layer and using componentZorder etc.. but still the problem is same.

I am not sure what causing JPanel layer to go back of JWebBrowser layer.

Comment: What version of Java are you running?

Comment: @jzd: I am using java version "1.6.0_26"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will bet that even though JWebBrowser derives eventually from JPanel that it behaves as a heavy-weight component with some native components. If so, there are limitations in what you can do, and you may want to read more about mixing heavy and light weight components together in a Swing app: [Mixing Heavy and Light Weight Components](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  Moving to a current version of Java 6 should fix this.

Comment: @jzd: I've heard that Java 1.6 behaves better in this regard but haven't tried it myself.

Comment: After a certain version of 1.6, I don't remember exactly which one, but basically it is not an issue.

Comment: @jzd: [As of the JDK 6 update 12 and JDK7 build 19](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/).

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I think you are right. But can u please tell me how can I make light-weight component to overlap heavy-weight component.

Answer (score 2):

If the web browser is created without any particular options, then it behaves like a heavy weight component. But if it is created with certain options, it can better mix.
For example: new JWebBrowser(JWebBrowser.constrainVisibility());

Have a look at the demo application to see all sorts of integration cases and more specifically at the additional features section.

Comment: Christopher, I thought about commenting on your issue tracker, but couldn't remember my SF password. Could you, please, answer my [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876710)?